# How to make it only require to click 4 time?

Tags: android, button, sequence, onclicklistener

I am current making a memory game. However it seems like I had to click 5 times instead of 4 times for it to work and the 1st click is a meaningless click. The game is like this, there are 4 buttons. Then the 4 buttons will blink randomly. The user has to click the buttons according to the sequence of the 4 buttons which had just blinked. This is my code.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            mClickedButtonIds.add(v.getId());

            if (mClickedButtonIds.size() > 4 ) 
            { 
                mClickedButtonIds.remove(0);            
                int[] mDesiredOrder = new int[] { ans1.getId(), ans2.getId(), ans3.getId(), ans4.getId() };
                if (mClickedButtonIds.get(0) == mDesiredOrder[0] 
                    && mClickedButtonIds.get(1) == mDesiredOrder[1] 
                    && mClickedButtonIds.get(2) == mDesiredOrder[2]
                    && mClickedButtonIds.get(3) == mDesiredOrder[3]
                    )
                {
                    tv1.setText("Correct!");
                }
                else 
                {
                    tv1.setText("Try Again!");
                }
                mClickedButtonIds.clear();
             }
           }
```

Is there any method to solve this problem. I know that the 1st click is to make it start the code below. However, I wanted to know if there are any other method that can make it just require 4 click to play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `if (mClickedButtonIds.size() > 4 )` checks whether 5 or more clicks were stored (including the current click) – change it to `>= 4` to correctly check for 4 clicks in total.

You should also remove the line `mClickedButtonIds.remove(0);` as this removes the first stored click, thus the first clicks is meaningless.

Comment: @Anatol If you edit your answer I'll delete this and upvote yours

Comment: dude you are so awesome man, you help me to solve a problem which I used whole day to solve. Actually i tried before use `>=4` but still cannot work. I didn't think of removing `mClickedButtonIds.remove(0);`. Actually I also not very sure the meaning of `mClickedButtonIds.remove(0);`.

Comment: @Anatol sorry I cannot delete an accepted answer, but I upvoted it as promised.

Comment: @Njol
Thanks. That sounds honestly. Good Luck to you!

Answer (score 1):

You should check your arrayList `mClickedButtonIds.size() > 3`, to get if initialized when 4 buttons are clicked.
And you should delete `mClickedButtonIds.remove(0);`

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    mClickedButtonIds.add(v.getId());

    if (mClickedButtonIds.size() > 3 ) {             
        int[] mDesiredOrder = new int[] { ans1.getId(), ans2.getId(), ans3.getId(), ans4.getId() };
        if (mClickedButtonIds.get(0) == mDesiredOrder[0] 
            && mClickedButtonIds.get(1) == mDesiredOrder[1] 
            && mClickedButtonIds.get(2) == mDesiredOrder[2]
            && mClickedButtonIds.get(3) == mDesiredOrder[3]
            )
        {
            tv1.setText("Correct!");
        }
        else 
        {
            tv1.setText("Try Again!");
        }
        mClickedButtonIds.clear();
     }
```

}

Comment: You should state what you changed and why as otherwise the asker won't learn anything from it.

Comment: I try to change it to 3 before, it does not work. If it is 3 it won't reach the 4th button thus not meting up with the condition.

Comment: size > 3. So 4 buttons will be clicked. You just shouldn't remove 1 clicked button.
`mClickedButtonIds.remove(0);`
What is the meaning of that string?